# Book pages rig and book cover rig don't align when moving the rigs

Tags: rigging

Im trying to create a book rig. The book cover and the inner pages have 2 separate rigs but the control bone in the book cover also controls the control bone in the inner pages rig.
My question is if there's a way for the book cover and the inner pages to align, it looks good when it's closed but when it's open the pages aren't in the correct place.

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=52gkvawJ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/52gkvawJ/) here it is!

Comment: @moonboots i added the link :)

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right way to rig, because the pages object is actually deforming when you open a book, so maybe you should not use any Copy constraint and instead move the bones manually so that the pages stick to the cover?

Comment: @moonboots ahh oke... I was wondering if you maybe know how to keep a point always aligned with a different point? Because right now i have the book case aligned with the pages, so the top page moves with the cover but i was wondering if it's possible to set the edge of the page to always stay aligned with the center of the book cover? i'll add the picture to the question